# How does CMake handle object dependency(.o.d) in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

GCC got an option `-MMD` to export `object dependency` (`.o.d`) for header files `incremental build`,

In Netbeans, there is an option called `enable dependency checking`, it will generate an `.dep.inc` and includes this file in make file automatically. My question is how to set this dependency handling in Qt Creator. Is there some extra setting for CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmake takes care of this automatically

http://www.aosabook.org/en/cmake.html

> It must do dependency scanning of C/C++ header files automatically.

Are you seeing behavior that indicates it isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, seemly i misunderstood `The IDE builds dependency checking logic into the generated Makefile` at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/depchecking.html. The link you gived  solves my confusion. Thx. :-)

Comment: Additionally, does Qt Creator provide native dependency analysis for c++?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about qt creator.

Comment: Thanks for your help again.